# Usage time of all (individual) applications in android [Usage]

Tags: java, android

I tried executing the code below, but this gives the "Last Time Used" of the applications.

```
public class UsageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<CustomUsageStats> mCustomUsageStatsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private DateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();

    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using (custom ViewHolder)
     */
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView mPackageName;
        private final TextView mLastTimeUsed;
        private final ImageView mAppIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mPackageName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_package_name);
            mLastTimeUsed = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_last_time_used);
            mAppIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        }

        public TextView getLastTimeUsed() {
            return mLastTimeUsed;
        }

        public TextView getPackageName() {
            return mPackageName;
        }

        public ImageView getAppIcon() {
            return mAppIcon;
        }
    }

    public UsageListAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.usage_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.getPackageName().setText(
                mCustomUsageStatsList.get(position).usageStats.getPackageName());
        long lastTimeUsed = mCustomUsageStatsList.get(position).usageStats.getLastTimeUsed();
        viewHolder.getLastTimeUsed().setText(mDateFormat.format(new Date(lastTimeUsed)));
        viewHolder.getAppIcon().setImageDrawable(mCustomUsageStatsList.get(position).appIcon);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCustomUsageStatsList.size();
    }

    public void setCustomUsageStatsList(List<CustomUsageStats> customUsageStats) {
        mCustomUsageStatsList = customUsageStats;
    }
}
```

So can anyone modify this and get the time used of each application (in foreground/background) and display it.

Comment: You don't have the only important part of the code here-  how you're getting the stats you're currently getting.  Although I don't think Android tracks what you want, so I don't think it will be possible.

Comment: Athough for foreground you can use usage.getTotalTimeInForeground().  Background isn't tracked.  ANd with Android's design it really can't be-  Android will kill you for resources whn in the background if needed and expect you to reinitialize.

Comment: it is possible to track the usage as there are many apps available on playstore (i.e. Breakfree).                                       
Also, I tried the above method (totaltimeinforeground) but it is giving a wrong output.